# Mixing Doxygen comments with cppcheck-suppress

Tags: c++, doxygen, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I have recently learned about:

```
// cppcheck-suppress noExplicitConstructor
A(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

to make cppcheck ignore some things I don't want to consider errors/warnings. However, I also depend on this style Doxygen comments:

```
/** This is A's constructor. */
A(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
/** This is A's constructor. 
  * cppcheck-suppress noExplicitConstructor
  */
A(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

but cppcheck doesn't pick up that suppression. Is there anyway to embed a cppcheck suppression in a Doxygen-style comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For the previous versions see the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40723965/revisions).)

This works for me:

```
class X {
  public:
  /** a very ugly constructor */
  // cppcheck-suppress uninitvar
  X() { int a; a++; }
};
```

Now `doxygen` will correctly see `"a very ugly constructor"` and `cppcheck` (installed just for this purpose) with command-line option `--inline-suppr` suppresses the warning `"(error) Uninitialized variable: a"`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's really ugly :) Let's see if there are any more built-in ways to cppcheck or something before I go with that.

Comment: @DavidDoria Is it? :-) I added another suggestion then.

Comment: @DavidDoria I installed cppcheck to try and completely rewrote the answer in result.

Comment: I'm not missing a change though right - it's the same thing you recommended before trying it, yes?

Comment: I just noticed I misread your question. Do you need to actually **embed** the suppress as a part of the Doxy comment?

Comment: Well it does not depend on a preprocessor, for one.

Comment: No, I just want Doxygen to work and also cppcheck to work. I think what you've suggested is fine as long as it works :) (which it sounds like now you've confirmed). That is, the Doxygen gets the /* */ comment and the cppcheck suppression indeed gets suppressed.

Comment: Yes, it's the same as what I added in revision 2, but back then it said I had no idea whether cppcheck would pick it correctly, and thus whether it would actually be of any help. Now I know it does there's no need for any other part of the previous wording.